# Running a non-WordPress PHP application on a site where WordPress is enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am writing a PHP/JavaScript application for my kids' summer camp.  I've got the app working locally, and I'm ready to set it up on the camp's live website, an Apache webserver running on Linux, owned by the camp's ISP.  I'm running into a problem: the site uses WordPress, with the root WordPress file installed at the webserver root:

```
/home/mycamp/public_html/wp
```

I tried creating a directory for my application under the webserver root alongside the WordPress directory, like this:

```
/home/mycamp/public_html/MyApp
```

but when I go to www.mycamp.org/MyApp, WordPress rewrites the URL to www.mycamp.org/blog/random-page-with-MyApp-in-the-title.

I tried putting the MyApp directory under /home/mycamp/public_html/wp, i.e.,

```
/home/mycamp/public_html/wp/MyApp
```

but the results were the same.

The WordPress docs suggest making edits to .htaccess, but I'm not sure how to do this without breaking the existing WP pages.  I don't want to change any of the camp's existing site, or turn off WP's RewriteEngine - I just want to set up my application on the site somewhere, completely independent of WordPress.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname1/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname2/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

borrowed from here
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40

Comment: Thank you!  Just to make sure I understand: in your example, would I replace subdirectoryname1 with my application's subdir (MyApp in my example above)?

Comment: Checked the docs and answered my own question: the [OR] is a logical OR operator.  So in my case, I would just have the line (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/MyApp/(.*)$, followed by RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L], which means "For any URL matching the RewriteCond, take no action ("-") and stop here ("[L]").  Thank you again for the pointer.